# Bootstrap 3 input padding issue

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have a bootstrap 3 webpage where I'm trying to increase the padding on inputs. My code looks like:

```
input[type='text'],
input[type='password'],
input[type='email'],
textarea
{
  padding-top:18px;
  padding-bottom:18px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drHc9/)

But on Firefox, the text is missing. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap sets a default height. You just need to add `height: auto`:

```css
input[type='text'],
input[type='password'],
input[type='email'],
textarea
{
  padding-top:18px;
  padding-bottom:18px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: auto;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drHc9/3/)